# How to save data object in RStudio?

Tags: r

I use RStudio 1.3.959
To run my experiments, I load data from csv, h5, txt, etc files. That data is saved in the RStudio environment although I did not save them on purpose. But one large data object which I loaded from txt file recently is not saved.
So, whenever RStudio faces some issues and quits I have to load that data object again. I tried to save it using `save.image()` which is supposed to save the entire environment. But I still have all the previously saved data but not that one I need.

What is the best way to save the data in RStudio environment to avoid loading it over and over?

Comment: have you tried `save` and `load` [?](https://rstudio-education.github.io/hopr/dataio.html)

Comment: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/05/how-to-save-and-load-datasets-in-r-an-overview/

Answer (score 0):

This might help

save data as a RDS object, use the saveRDS function.

you can refer to https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/readRDS